# How to add multiple where condition in Pyspark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

This is my SQL query which I am trying to convert into PySpark, but getting output as 0 results:

```
select acct, id,load_date,ptc
from pvc
where acct in ('C','I') and load_date='2024-02-08'
```

Pyspark query as follows:

```
master_data= spark.read.table('my_table')
master_data_df=master_data.filter(col('load_date')=='2024-02-08' & (col('acct').isin('C','I')))\.select('acct','id','ptc','load_date')

master_data_df.distinct().count() is showing 0 results
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: I think, you can cast load_date to `date` type then re run code.

Comment: You are missing brackets for `(col('load_date')=='2024-02-08')`.  otherwise `&` is taking precedence over `==` and read as `col('load_date') == (x & y)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
master_data_df = master_data.filter(
    (col("load_date") == "2024-02-08") & (col("acct").isin("C", "I"))
).select("acct", "id", "ptc", "load_date")
```

separating individual where conditions with parentheses '()' will make it more clearer for the parser